# how to fill combobox in datagridview from database in vb.net and load default first unit or items in combobox

Tags: vb.net

my issue is how to fill in specific column  and make load first unit by default when load form

```
   Dim com As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn


    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
    dt.Clear()


    da = New SqlDataAdapter("select name_unit from unit where item_code =" & DataGridView1(0, DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index).Value & " ", Con)

    da.Fill(dt)



    com.Name = "name_unit"
    com.DataSource = dt


    com.ValueMember = "name_unit"
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add(com)
```

Comment: Use the DataTable.DefaultView as the ComboBox DataSource, set the DisplayMember to the name of the Field or the `ColumnName` used for display (since you have just one Field here, in this case is what is used, but anyway...). Dispose of the objects you created: the DataAdapter and the DataTable. Since you're using a `DataGridView1.CurrentRow`, you should also show when/where this code is called.

Comment: i want to select deference unit in database must to call it so i use dataadapter and this code load combo box by unit as example kilo or ton .my problem is what is code to link between combobox in datagrid view and this code

Comment: I really don't know what you're trying to say here. It's ok to use a DataAdapter to fill the DataTable. However, you need to dispose of it. More important, use the DataTable.DefaultView as a `ComboBox.DataSource`. Then, dispose of the DataTable, too.

Comment: i'm sorry , but how i can use DataTable.DefaultView as  combobox

Comment: `com.DataSource = dt.DefaultView`.